# Extract sub site logo with MS Graph (or any other way)

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

I need to extract sub sites logo and show it in a list. This is something I thought could be made with MS Graph, but in MS explorer I can't find the picture element. Only site ID, members, etc.

Surely it must be a simple way to extract the site logo with either MS Graph or REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below REST endpoint it is working at my end, I have tried it out in Sharepoint online as well as Sharepoint 2013:

```
/_api/Web?$select=Title,SiteLogoUrl
```